# Solution Folder not creating in VSTemplate ProjectCollection

Tags: c#, visual-studio-templates

I am using the below code to generate a new template. The issue is it is not creating the solution folder and adding projects in it.

```
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" Type="ProjectGroup" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005">
  <TemplateData>
<Name>DDD Framework</Name>
<Description>Domain Driven Design</Description>
<ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
<ProjectSubType>
</ProjectSubType>
<SortOrder>1000</SortOrder>
<CreateNewFolder>true</CreateNewFolder>
<DefaultName>DDD_Framework</DefaultName>
<ProvideDefaultName>true</ProvideDefaultName>
<LocationField>Enabled</LocationField>
<EnableLocationBrowseButton>true</EnableLocationBrowseButton>
<Icon>Logo.png</Icon>
</TemplateData>
<TemplateContent>
<ProjectCollection>
  <SolutionFolder Name="01 Core">
    <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$projectname$.Data">
      Data\MyTemplate.vstemplate
    </ProjectTemplateLink>
    <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$projectname$.Objects">
      Objects\MyTemplate.vstemplate
    </ProjectTemplateLink>
  </SolutionFolder>
</ProjectCollection>
```

So, when new project is created with template, it is not creating solution folder `01 Core` as mentioned `<SolutionFolder Name="01 Core">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some analysis and adding this tag `<CreateInPlace>true</CreateInPlace>` solution folders are creating and it finally works!!!

```
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" Type="ProjectGroup" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005">
    <TemplateData>
         <CreateInPlace>true</CreateInPlace>
    </TemplateData>
</VSTemplate>
```

Comment: I have the same problem, this solution doesn't work for me. "VS 2019 16.11.3"